# Itunes connect screenshots upload

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, screenshot

When I edit my application data, I get this message:
Screenshots and app previews for the largest display sizes of your app’s 
primary localization must be uploaded directly.

Screenshots for all sizes primary localization are loaded. I've tried to change primary language - result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue, contacted to Apple Support, they tried helping me via remote desktop. No luck. Still waiting for the solution.

Watched the keynote and it works there on stage (of course) but we can't upload 5.5" screenshots.

Tried a lot of "solutions" that came up on other forums, none of them helped rectifying it.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. None of other "solutions" not helped me too. Apple Support write me: "We have noticed that some developer’s are facing this issue due to their screenshots." Peter, please, write me, if you find a solution.

Comment: I had to create a new app bundle ID and a new app in iTunes Connect. This time everything went smooth. 

Unfortunately there is no way to delete the previous one so i renamed the title of it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple. You must create new app bundle and submission will work.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. But what can we do with old app bundle and users, which use it. When we update the app - we must update both bundle apps - is it right?